# Loop keeps resetting

Tags: vba, excel, infinite-loop

I have the following code

```
Sub Split_data()

' Split_data

Dim iCtr As Long
Dim Total As Long
Dim Iterations As Long
Dim FilePath As String

' Save path for new files
FilePath = "C:\DataFiles"

' Create folder to store files
If FileFolderExists(FilePath) Then
    ' Delete first row with obsolete data
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Else
    MkDir (FilePath)
    ' Delete first row with obsolete data
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If

Total = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count
Iterations = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Total / 2, 0)

' Generate the files
For iCtr = 1 To Iterations
    Generate_Files iCtr, FilePath
Next iCtr

End Sub
```

The code itself works properly except for 1 thing, the moment I have finished my For loop, my counter mysteriously resets back to 1 and it keeps looping.

So if I got 5 rows, it loops 3 times with the `iCtr` value going up properly as it should, but once the 3rd loop is done, it all of a sudden jumps back to 1 and starts all over.

So anyone see zhy, cause I've tried going through it a couple times step by step, but I can't find zhy it jumps back to 1

Rest of the code if it matters:

```
Function Generate_Files(iCtr As Long, FilePath As String)
'
' Generates files which contain copied data of first copied x rows after which these rows are deleted
'

' Create variables
Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim CurrPath As String

' Stop screen flickering
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Initialise variables
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)

    ' Create new workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add(1)

wb2.Activate
Sheets(1).Name = "data"
Set ws2 = Worksheets("data")

' Set path of created file
CurrPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

' Copy data from wb1
wb1.Activate
ws1.Select
Rows("1:2").Select
Selection.Copy

' -!-
' Copy done afterwards to prevent issues with copied values disappearing from copy clipboard while creating new file
' -!-

' Activate wb2
wb2.Activate
ws2.Select

' Paste data in wb2
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

' Remove first x lines from original file
wb1.Activate
Rows("1:2").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

' Save & close wb2
wb2.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\DataFiles\Split Data" & iCtr)
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function



Public Function FileFolderExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean

On Error GoTo EarlyExit
If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True

EarlyExit:
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Very strange. Could you try with a breakpoint in the For loop to see if `Iterations` correctly shows 5 and not 3 when the loop begins and if it somehow doesn't change.  The only other explanation is that the code is throwing some error and exiting without anything being displayed on the 3rd iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare your function like this:

```
Function Generate_Files(ByVal iCtr As Long, ByVal FilePath As String)
' the rest of the function definition
```

By default the arguments of a VBA `Function` or `Sub` are `ByRef`, which means that the called function/subroutine may modify the arguments from the calling function/subroutine. `ByVal` will prevent that.

**Later Edit**

The alternative is to force the compiler to convert the argument passing to `ByVal` in the calling function:

```
For iCtr = 1 To Iterations
    Generate_Files (iCtr), FilePath
Next iCtr
```

as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chy4288y.aspx).

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, however I still find it weird as I don't change the values of either of them in any of the called functions. But then again some things never make sense. But thanks none the less.

Comment: @Firefox333 I saw that actually the function didn't change `iCal`, I just thought that you didn't paste the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to confirm that code before or after the loop isn't executing again. It's possible the entire Split_data function got called again, or some function recursion of some sort caused multiple instances of this function to be executing at once. Try outputting some debug text before and after the loop and make sure it's only going into it once.

Comment: I tried adding a `MsgBox` which shows the value of my counter. That works. However the moment I remove the `MsgBox` function it starts with looping indefinitely again.

Comment: I think putting the MsgBox inside the loop, although helpful for one purpose, would not expose the potential problem that Split_data might be called recursively or more than once. It would still be worthwhile to try a MsgBox before the loop and if it appears more than once, you can conclude that the loop is not starting over, another copy of the loop has started instead.